# JSF + Primefaces: Datatable wont fill with items

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I just wanted to set up a data-table Example for an educational presentation. In class we did a little Program to manage a couple of Movies.
Now we should create a JSF Page and just list those Movies of a specific Director.
So. 
my xhtml file:
http://pastebin.com/UdTxujZk

my controller for that file:
http://pastebin.com/4AGTJ07q

i have no idea why i cant show those movies with title and directors in a primefaces data table. i had a look at the example and tried to implement it. when im searchin for any director the data table is setting up correctly, so if im lookin for Spielberg (we have 3 films with him in our database) the table is setting up with three cells etc.

sorry for my bad english and maybe the mixed language in the code. Hopefully someone understands my problem and can help me!

would be awesome!

/edit

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Aufgabenblatt6</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Auswahl</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="regName" value="Regisseur"></h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="regName" value="#{accessDialog.directorName}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="Suchen" action="#{accessDialog.findMovies()}"></h:commandButton>                                 
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{accessDialog.selectedMovies}"></h:outputLabel>
    <p:dataTable id="table" var="movie" value="#{accessDialog.getAusgabe()}">
        <p:column headerText="Director">
            <h:outputText value="#{movie.director}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="test" sortBy="#{movie.title}" headerText="Titel">
            <h:outputText value="#{movie.title}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

the jave file:

```
package de.hsos.kbse.access;

import de.hsos.kbse.movie.impl.Movie;
import de.hsos.kbse.movie.impl.MovieLister;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author lars
 */
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class AccessDialog implements Serializable {
private String directorName;
private String selectedMovies;
private Movie[] movies;
private List<Movie> ausgabe;
@Inject
private MovieLister mL;

public AccessDialog() {
    this.directorName = "";
    this.selectedMovies = "";
    this.movies = new Movie[0];
    this.ausgabe = new ArrayList<>();
}


public void findMovies(){
    setMovies(this.mL.moviesDirectedBy(this.directorName));
    if(getMovies() != null){
        for (Movie tmp : getMovies()) {
            this.selectedMovies += tmp.getTitle()+"; ";
            this.ausgabe.add(tmp);
        }
    } else {
        this.selectedMovies = "Zu diesem Autor sind keine Filme vorhanden!";
    }
}

/**
 * @return the directorName
 */
public String getDirectorName() {
    return directorName;
}

/**
 * @param directorName the directorName to set
 */
public void setDirectorName(String directorName) {
    this.directorName = directorName;
}

/**
 * @return the selectedMovies
 */
public String getSelectedMovies() {
    return selectedMovies;
}

/**
 * @param selectedMovies the selectedMovies to set
 */
public void setSelectedMovies(String selectedMovies) {
    this.selectedMovies = selectedMovies;
}

/**
 * @return the movies
 */
public Movie[] getMovies() {
    return movies;
}

/**
 * @param movies the movies to set
 */
public void setMovies(Movie[] movies) {
    this.movies = movies;
}

/**
 * @return the ausgabe
 */
public List<Movie> getAusgabe() {
    return ausgabe;
}

/**
 * @param ausgabe the ausgabe to set
 */
public void setAusgabe(List<Movie> ausgabe) {
    this.ausgabe = ausgabe;
}
```

}

Its workin now. I had @Named before my Movie class. This causes the non existing title etc. But now i tried something with primefaces and its workin so far. But when i want to sort those films i have to search again for the director. If im clicking at the column there are no records and then after i searched again they are sorted.

if you could help me with that it would be awesome aswell ;) i guess its just a stupid mistake which is obvious for someone who is more used to jsf etc.

Comment: can you post code here as well? the link you posted i cannot open it due to security policy

Comment: I edited it and added a new question cause i solved the old problem!

Comment: your bean is Request scoped so when ever you make a new request it will initialize again, try changing it to view scope